# I want to put information for 1 value in multiple rows to a unique row with those informations all in multiple columns (example on description)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a large table that goes like the code below. As you can see, there is multiple rows where person1 has the same value.

```
d <- c(01, 02, 03, 04)
h <- c("19:00", "19:00", "07:00", "07:00")
p1 <- c(123, 321, 123, 123)
p2 <- c(321, 345, 567, 567)

df <- data.frame(date = d, hours = h, person1 = p1, person2 = p2)
```

```
# date   hours  person1  person2  

# 01      19:00   123      321

# 02      19:00   321      345

# 03      07:00   123      567

#04       07:00   123      567
# ...    ...    ...      ...
```

I want to create a table where the main object is person1 (without repetition, like for the value 123 in the table abova) with all the values of date, hours and person2 this person1 had contact to.

Like this

```
# person1 date1  date2...  hours1  hours2 ... person2  person3 ...

# 123     01     03        07:00   19:00      321     567

# 321     02     NA        19:00   NA         345     NA
```

I wanted to come up with something written, but I couldn't find a way to do that

I was thinking that maybe I should create a new table with all the hours and dates possivel in columns as dummies and use `dplyr` to check, the combinations that each person in person1 has relations. But i'm afraid that that would create a table with a huge number of dummies

Comment: Yes. I want to created a table to make cluster graphics with the relations for each person, based on the hours, dates and people who this person had contact

Comment: Please check the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

If it is based on 'person1', duplicates then, create a sequence column (`rowid` - from `data.table` or do a `group_by(person1)` and create the column with `row_number()`), and then use `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(rn = rowid(person1)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = c(date, hours, person2),
           names_sep="")
# A tibble: 2 x 7
#  person1 date1 date2 hours1 hours2 person21 person22
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     123     1     3 19:00  20:00       321      567
#2     321     2    NA 15:00  <NA>        345       NA
```

Comment: Awesome result! But its repeating values to the columns. So if there is a person1 that has 960 rows where there is  "07:00" in hours, it creates 960 columns for this same 07:00. I'd like to have only 1 column for the value 07:00, one for the value 19:00 and so on

Comment: @ApoloReis may be you need `rowid(person1, date, hours)` as the input example is a small one, it is not entirely clear

Comment: I edited it so you can see what happens when I try your last tip. Its better than the first code, but if possible, instead of giving me a list of all the combinations, I wanted it to just give me each value only once per person1.

Comment: Like, for person 123 it gives me ``c("19:00", "07:00", "07:00")``. I want it to give me "19:00" and "07:00" once at different columns.

Comment: @ApoloReis can you please update your post with another small example and expected output that shows this issue. thanks